# Select cell to copy data

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I found this code to copy selected rows from a multi-column multi-select ListBox to my sheet. How can I set the cell where the first selected row should be copied to?

I can change the Excel column but not the row. It always starts in the first one (for example A1 or B1)

```
Dim Litem As Long, LbRows As Long, LbCols As Long
Dim bu As Boolean
Dim Lbloop As Long, Lbcopy As Long
Dim m As Variant

LbRows = ListBox2.ListCount - 1
LbCols = ListBox2.ColumnCount - 1

For Litem = 0 To LbRows
    If ListBox2.Selected(Litem) = True Then
        bu = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If bu = True Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range(sCell).End(xlUp)            'sCell is the selected Cell

        For Litem = 0 To LbRows
            If ListBox2.Selected(Litem) = True Then 'Row selected
                'Increment variable for row transfer range
                Lbcopy = Lbcopy + 1
                For Lbloop = 0 To LbCols
                    'Transfer selected row to relevant row of transfer range
                    .Cells(Lbcopy, Lbloop + 1) = ListBox2.List(Litem, Lbloop)

                Next Lbloop
            End If
        Next
        For m = 0 To LbCols
            With ActiveSheet.Range(sCell).End(xlUp)
            End With
        Next
    End With
Else
     MsgBox "Nichts ausgewählt", vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried to read and understand the code on your own and do the changes by yourself before posting the question here? If so, why weren't you able to succeed. What happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried to understand it and allready modified it. I changed the Range the selected rows are copied to, but this only affected the column of the sheet, not the row.  I don't know where the row is defined. Im rather new to vba and am stretched to my limits fast.

Comment: Seems to me the `Lbcopy` is the variable you should take a closer look

Comment: ^^ Especially when there is a comment saying `'Increment variable for row transfer range` highlighting the fact that `Lbcopy` is the variable used to specify the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the variable responsible for "looping through the rows" is `Lbcopy`. You are correctly declaring the variable at the beginning of the code, but the first time you ever use the variable is in here:

```
'Increment variable for row transfer range
Lbcopy = Lbcopy + 1
```

At this point, the value of the variable is `0` because you haven't assigned any value to it.
This means that the first time you step into the `For` loop, you are roughly saying `Lbcopy = 0 + 1`.

One way of determining the start row is to assign an initial value for the variable before the `For Litem = 0 To LbRows`, like this:

```
Lbcopy = 9     ' <--- will start copying from row 10
For Litem = 0 To LbRows
    If ListBox2.Selected(Litem) = True Then 'Row selected
        'Increment variable for row transfer range
        Lbcopy = Lbcopy + 1   ' <-- will turn the value of first iteration to 10
        For Lbloop = 0 To LbCols
            'Transfer selected row to relevant row of transfer range
            .Cells(Lbcopy, Lbloop + 1) = ListBox2.List(Litem, Lbloop)

        Next Lbloop
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I was able to modify the code to my needs.